# X has 1 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 10 features as input

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, linear-regression, feature-engineering

I've seen similar questions asked here but they all seem to be caused by a different problem. I've tried reshaping and making sure it's a 2d array but i keep getting this error. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model
d = pd.read_csv("http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~jgillett/451/data/mtcars.csv")
X = d[['cyl','disp','hp','drat','wt','qsec','vs','am','gear','carb']]
y=d[['mpg']].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = model.predict(X_test).reshape(-1,1)
y_test=y_test.reshape(-1,1)
model.score(pred,y_test)
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

The arguments for `model.score()` should be `X_test` and `y_test`, not `pred` and `y_test`.

From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score):

```
Parameters
        ----------
        X : array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Test samples. For some estimators this may be a precomputed
            kernel matrix or a list of generic objects instead with shape
            ``(n_samples, n_samples_fitted)``, where ``n_samples_fitted``
            is the number of samples used in the fitting for the estimator.
        y : array-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_outputs)
            True values for `X`.
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model
d = pd.read_csv("http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~jgillett/451/data/mtcars.csv")
X = d[['cyl','disp','hp','drat','wt','qsec','vs','am','gear','carb']]
y=d[['mpg']].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = model.predict(X_test).reshape(-1,1)
y_test=y_test.reshape(-1,1)
model.score(X_test,y_test)
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can explain what goes wrong, and what does your code fix

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate the quality of your predictions `y_test` vs `pred`, you have to use some regression metrics like:

[R2 score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#r2-score-the-coefficient-of-determination):

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print(r2_score(y_test, pred))
# Out: 0.0058351676336382274
```

[Mean Absolute Error](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-absolute-error):

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
print(mean_absolute_error(y_test, pred))
# Out: 4.268248988378566
```

[Mean Squared Error](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-squared-error):

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
print(mean_squared_error(y_test, pred))
# Out: 30.227426389844176
```

[Mean absolute percentage error](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-absolute-percentage-error):

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
print(mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_test, pred))
# Out: 0.23155559024744402
```

The last metric is interesting since you can understand it immediately because it's a value between 0 and 1. Here, you have a mean absolute error of +/- 23% between real values and predicted values.

There is more metrics to evaluate the quality of your predictions. When you use `model.score` the score is the coefficient of determination R2, which is the same of `r2_score` metric:

```
>>> model.score(X_test, y_test)
0.0058351676336382274

>>> r2_score(y_test, pred)
0.0058351676336382274
```